# I am trying to switch from one Fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to move/ switch from one Fragment to another Fragment but when I do this Android app stops unfortunately
I have attached all the code files bellow. **Please Tell Me What Should I Do**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mnaum.myapplication;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.text.TextDirectionHeuristicCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button button1, button2, button3;
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    listeners();
}

private void listeners() {
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentA fragmentA=new FragmentA();
            transaction.add(R.id.framel,fragmentA);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
            transaction.replace(R.id.framel,fragmentB);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}

private void init() {
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);

}
}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
package com.example.mnaum.myapplication;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_a,null);
    return view;
}
}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
package com.example.mnaum.myapplication;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_b,null);
    return view;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mnaum.myapplication.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:id="@+id/linLayout"
   android:weightSum="3">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/btn3"/>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linLayout"
    android:id="@+id/framel"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    >

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_fragment_a**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0ff"
tools:context="com.example.mnaum.myapplication.FragmentA">
```

**activity_fragment_b**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mnaum.myapplication.FragmentB"
android:background="#f0f">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please post your error logcat

Comment: Hi Muhammand post your error logcat so we give you proper solution,

Comment: Initialize your manage and transaction in onCreate() method of your MainActivity class

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialise object before replace fragment

```
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
```

like

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            FragmentB fragmentB=new FragmentB();
            transaction.replace(R.id.framel,fragmentB);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity make FragmentManager manager and FragmentTransaction transaction as global where they are now. and initialize them in OnCreate() method.

It should be :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     manager=getFragmentManager();
 transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    init();
    listeners();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this...
Changes only in MainActivity.java.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button1, button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                openFragment(fragmentA);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                openFragment(fragmentB);
            }
        });

    }

    private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framel, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your requirement for me its working fine

try it out...and from your code rather than using fragmentmanager() better use getsupportfragmentmanager()

this is my code:

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1,b2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            BlankFragment bf=new BlankFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,bf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            BlankFragment2 bf2=new BlankFragment2();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,bf2).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have written a similar code for you.

```
   private void AddBottomNavigation() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
       BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
      bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
 BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_charge:
                    fragment = new ChargeFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_rank:
                    fragment = new RankFragment();
                    break;
            }
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps you.